# Iterate through NSMutableArray to add object in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a JSON response with an array of companies.
Then I am iterating through the array in order to add them as Company objects. My issue here is that If I do `[[Company alloc]init];` inside the loop I will create a memory leak. If I alloc-init out of the loop all my values are the same. What is the best approach?
Code below:

```
resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
responseArray = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"companies"];

 Company *com = [[Company alloc]init];
            //Looping through the array and creating the objects Movie and adding them on a new array that will hold the objects
            for(int i=0;i<responseArray.count;i++){


                helperDictionary =(NSDictionary*)[responseArray objectAtIndex:i];

                com.title = [helperDictionary objectForKey:@"company_title"];
                NSLog(@"company title %@",com.title);
                [resultArray addObject:com];

            }
```

company title is always the same value in the result array. If I put the Company alloc-init in the loop the values are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to create a new `Company` object for each entry in the dictionary?  In that case you must create a new instance each time:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArray) {
    Company company = [[Company new] autorelease];
    company.title = dict[@"company_title"];
    [resultArray addObject:company];
}
```

Comment: Creating new instance each time with the same variable name would cause leaks, right?

Comment: @BlackM No.  You are storing a reference to the object in the array.

Comment: I read that if you initialise an object in a loop, you are losing the reference  to that object and it can't be freed. Is that completely wrong? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Well you are not losing it as you are making the array manage the object.  Without the last line, you would have a memory leak, if you are using manual reference counting.

Comment: If using manual memory management, then wouldn't company need to be released after being added to the array?

Comment: @JamesP Indeed; there should be an `autorelease` there if MRR, and not ARC, is being used.

Comment: @BlackM Please note, I've updated my answer for manual reference counting.  An `autorelease` is required when creating the object.

Comment: @trojanfoe I already upvoted but my question was about ARC. Anyway I got the point.